# openssl convert apple .cer to .p12 i have only one file cer

Tags: openssl, apple-push-notifications, x509certificate

how can i generate **.p12** file by having one **.cer** file downloaded from apple by step  by step .

I read a lot of topics about this issue, but i feel miss something  here , many topics described how to convert **.cer** to **.pem** OK, then convert **.key** to **.pem** :( i haven't **.key** file .

```
openssl x509 -inform DER -in certificate.cer -out certificate.pem
```

What next

So any one can help me here ,Remember i have just only **.CER** file .

Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.P12` or `PFX` file is a file that contains both, X.509 certificate and associated private key. PFX doesn't support certificates without keys.

`.CER` is a plain X.509 certificate with public key only. It doesn't contain private key. And by knowing only public key you cannot restore the associated private key. Therefore, what you are asking is not possible without having private key.

Comment: ok then, how to create private key with password using openssl.

Comment: Thousands threads on SO. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl